# How to detect when an if statement exits

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've been having this issue that I've been working around for some time after working on a clean switch/case statement for python...

The issue I'm having is with nested context leakage:

```
value = 10

switch( value ) # sets context result to 10

if case( 10 ):

    subvalue = 20

    switch( subvalue ) # changes context result from 10 to 20

    if case( 5 ):
        pass

    if case( 15, 20 ):
        pass

if case( 20 ): # this shouldn't execute (workaround: place this above case(10))
    pass
```

How can I auto-detect the exit clause of an if statement to properly reset the context without manually changing this frontward code?

The code for the switch/case functions is currently very basic:

```
class Null(object): pass

context = [Null()] # avoids error cases

def switch( test ): context[0] = test

def case( *comparators ): return context[0] in comparators
```

Note: Methods requiring ast or dis/inspect to dynamically modify the script before executing are viable here.

Comment: Can you post the code for `case` and `switch`?

Comment: currently, it's basically just setting a relative context variable, but alright, gimme a sec.

Comment: This is a hard problem ... not sure if anything like this is built into python, an if block is not even its own scope, variables declared inside the if block are still valid outside ... In other languages I would say something like "have switch be a macro, that creates a local object, and you get the end of the if clause through the destructor call", but this doesn't work with python ...

Comment: If you're dealing with contexts, you probably need a _context manager_ (a class that implements the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods). Then you could store the context in this class and manipulate it.

Comment: @ForceBru the problem there is that requires `with switch( ... ):` which looks nothing like what others would expect. Although, while possible to do dynamically with ast, it's still quite difficult to insert cases into the context.

Comment: @interjay haha I just caught that (`context` not global) and fixed it, the reason I missed that is because I wrote the code from memory, the current code I'm working on is actually an unfinished class and no longer has that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
elif case( 20 ): # this shouldn't execute (workaround: place this above case(10))
    pass
```

Another possible solution is to make `context` a stack:

```
def switch(test):
    context.append(test)

def case(*args):
    ret = context[-1] in args
    if ret:
        context.pop()
    return ret
```

And then `if case(20)` will act on `value` if one of the cases for `subvalue` evaluated to `True`. There's no way to check if any of the `case` calls evaluated to `True`, though.

You can solve this with a context manager and `elif`:

```
def case(*args):
    ...

class switch:
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.variable = variable

    def __enter__(self):
        global case
        case = self.case

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        # Don't forget to clean up
        global case
        def case(*args):
            ...

    def case(self, *args):
        return self.variable in args

with switch(6):
    if case(5):
        print('five')
    elif case(6, 7):
        print('six or seven')
    else:
        print('what is this??')
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something stupidly simple, how could I've missed the if statement in the case function, thank you :)